# Problem with Getting Query Parameter from URL in Next.js API Route

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma

I am working on a Next.js project (version 14) where I have implemented a product search feature. The search functionality is handled by a Search component, and the relevant code is as follows:

```
// Search component in Search.tsx
"use client";

import { useSearchParams, usePathname, useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { useDebouncedCallback } from 'use-debounce';

export default function Search({ placeholder }: { placeholder: string }) {
  const searchParams = useSearchParams();
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const { replace } = useRouter();

  const handleSearch = useDebouncedCallback((term) => {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(searchParams || '');
    if (term) {
      params.set('q', term);
    } else {
      params.delete('q');
    }
    replace(`${pathname}?${params.toString()}`);
  }, 300);
  
  return (
    <div className="relative">
      <input
        className="peer block mt-0 w-full rounded-md border border-gray-200 py-[9px] pr-10 text-sm outline-2 placeholder:text-gray-500"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        onChange={(e) => {
          handleSearch(e.target.value);
        }}
        defaultValue={searchParams?.get('q')?.toString()}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

In the GET handler of my API route (app/api/products/route.ts), I am trying to retrieve the query parameter from the URL like this:

```
// app/api/products/route.ts
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from "next/server";

export const GET = async (req: NextRequest) => {
  const { searchParams } = req.nextUrl;
  const query = searchParams.get("q");
  console.log(query);

  return NextResponse.json({ query });
};
```

When I test the search by entering "test search product," the URL is updated correctly to /products?q=test+search+product. However, the query parameter in the response is always null. I expected it to be "test search product."

want to use this query parameter to fetch data from the API using Prisma. Any suggestions on what might be causing the issue or how I can correctly retrieve the query parameter? Thanks!

Comment: How and where you are calling the `app/api/products/route.ts`?